# При вставке тега <img> код слетает

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте!
Имеется код, который заменяет значение в определенном блоке:

```
<a href="javascript:ReplaceContentInContainer('example1div','Home is clicked')">
```

Блок:

```
    <div 
   id="example1div" 
   style="
   padding:10px; 
   text-align:center;">
Project Log
</div>
```

Скрипт:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ReplaceContentInContainer(id,content) {
var container = document.getElementById(id);
container.innerHTML = content;
}
</script>
```

Однако, если вставить в замену (example1div) картинку, тег имг, то код слетает и происходит что-то непонятное, например:

```
<img src="https://pp.vk.me/c543103/v543103564/1c7f0/Jkk_3iw_NFU.jpg" alt="">
```

То код слетает.
В чем проблема?
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Что значит "код слетает"? Только что запустил ваш код - всё работает. Приведите ещё пример кода как вызываете функцию

Comment: http://codepen.io/Ants0li/pen/WxPNXB
Вот, на второй строчке код слетает.

Comment: Кавычки экранируйте. И приведите вопрос в порядок, приведите здесь (не на стороннем сайте) **минимальный код**, который не работает.

Comment: `href="javascript:ReplaceContentInContainer('example1div','Home is clicked <br><br> <img src="https://pp.vk.me/c543103/v543103564/1c7f0/Jkk_3iw_NFU.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="300"> ')">` 
Вот эта строка не работает корректно, хотя я пытался поставить кавычки несколькими способами.

Comment: Получилось. Всем спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Раз получилось, ответ прими нажатием на галочку.

Answer (score 2):

Кавычки в кавычках в кавычках. Вероятно, html-разметка не парсится корректно.

Подробнее в [другом ответе](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/456039/178988).